# Reading Word-file (*.dot) from program resources

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

Have a set of Word-templates (files *.dot) and a little program, which create new files base on that templates. It's works fine, but the goal is to make all in one exe-file.
I see the solution is to move templates files into program resources. But I don't know, how then I will read them from resources. Tell me, please, how to do this. 
Maybe you can advise me another solution.

Now, my code is:

```
procedure TfmMain.CreateDocument0;
var
  TempleateFileName: string;
  WordApp, Document: OleVariant;

  procedure FillBookmark(BookmarkName, bText: string);
  var
    Range: OleVariant;
  begin
    if Document.Bookmarks.Exists(BookmarkName) then
    begin
      Range := Document.Bookmarks.Item(BookmarkName).Range;
      Range.Text := bText;
    end;
  end;
begin
  TempleateFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Templates\0.dot';
  try
    WordApp := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(E.Message), PChar(fmMain.Caption), MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  try
    Document := WordApp.Documents.Add(TempleateFileName, False);

    FillBookmark('ObjectType', edt0ObjectType.Text);
    ...

    WordApp.Visible := True;
    WordApp.Activate;
  finally
    WordApp := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

That is, I should change this line:
`Document := WordApp.Documents.Add(TempleateFileName, False);`

Read not from file, but from program resource.

Comment: Two steps. 1. Add the files to your executable as compiled resource. 2. Extract the files at runtime and save them to disk. At this point Excel is able to read the file and you can continue as before.

Comment: Yes, David, I think about that, but that variant have some limits. Will use it if I will not find out some other solutions.

Comment: Consider using a RAM disk if it is compulsory not to store the file on an HDD/SSD. Or consider storing the file in *.rtf format and feed it to TRichEdit.

Comment: OT: Regarding `MessageBox(Self.Handle, PChar(E.Message), PChar(fmMain.Caption), MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);` - the `Self.` before `Handle` is superfluous but doesn't harm. But normally you shouldn't refer to `frmMain` inside methods of `TfrmMain`.

Comment: And `MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR` should better be `MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR` as you want to combine bitmasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word cannot open documents from memory. Not only does it not have such a feature, you must also bear in mind that Word executes in a separate process. It cannot see the memory in your process, even if it were able to open documents from memory.

If you do put the documents into linked resources then you will need to extract them to file before asking Word to open them.

Comment: [Actually can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478386.aspx), but in .NET.

Comment: @Victoria Word isn't doing that. It's a library for processing Office OpenXML documents. The question here is about Word automation.